# Links in Internet Explorer opening blank page Apps Script

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-apps-script, internet-explorer-11

I have built a web app using Google apps script, and I have a peculiar problem that HTML links are working fine in Google Chrome, FireFox and Microsoft Edge, but when I click on a link using Internet Explorer 11 (on several machines), the browser will sometimes open an empty tab. Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_blank">
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="http://www.oecd.org/dac/stats/officialdevelopmentassistancedefinitionandcoverage.htm" > click1 </a>
    <br>
    <a href="http://www.google.com"> click2 </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

The second link works, while the first does not. I have no explanation for this and any help would be much appreciated. Also note that this code DOES work in chrome so the links are not broken.

Edit: This is the .gs code:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('TestingLinks')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

Comment: Remove the `target = "blank"` attribute from the `a` tags and change: `<base target="_top">` to `<base target="_blank">`  See if that makes any difference.

Comment: @SandyGood no effect unfortunately.

Comment: Are you using IFRAME Sandbox Mode?

Comment: @ocordova yes does that make a difference?

Comment: Your .gs code looks fine, Maybe removing the spaces between between attribute name and its value? e.g. target="_blank" and href="

Comment: @ocordova edited but no luck regardless.

Comment: @SandyGood any other ideas? I could start a bounty..

Comment: Does this behavior occur frequently using Internet Explorer? If you think this is not a code implementation issue, you might want to file [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/entry) for apps script's public issue tracker.

Comment: I agree with @Mr.Rebot, can you reproduce the same behavior creating a standalone .html file locally and then open it with Internet Explorer?